# Artificial Intelligence Studies

Tags: artificial-intelligence

My task is to conduct a study on `artificial intelligence` that answer maybe just 20 questions.
I tried to look for a study and term papers on google and i'm having a hard time to find some related literature to start my study.
My knowledge on `artificial intelligence` is small.

Where can i find some related literature for the said study? My goal is just to make an AI that answer question related to processes that our school conduct. Please be easy on me. I know that i'm a noob.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I have a hard time understanding what you are looking for.

Comment: @static_rtti need related literature that studies about AI that response to the user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing

And build from there. You can use Google Scholar to find actual scientific papers once you've found the keywords you want.